# Flex/bison scanner fails on unput() when loading text with yyscan_bytes()

Tags: flex-lexer

I am adapting an already-fully-functional parser to read from a client-provided text buffer, so I am following the examples I found on this site, which have me load the buffer using yyscan_bytes().  Unfortunately, this leads to a fatal error using the existing grammar due to this (long-existing) Flex rule:

```
.|"\n"                  { BEGIN INIT; unput(yytext[0]); }
```

This rule is the first one hit when I parse any input, and the unput() always fails with the "flex scanner push-back overflow" error.  I am not quite sure what this all-purpose rule is doing, but taking it out causes everything to fail in other ways.  Any ideas or enlightment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That action unconditionally sets the start condition to `INIT`. (Actually, it's not quite unconditional. It requires that the input contain at least one byte; otherwise, the EOF action will be performed instead.)

However, `unput(yytext[0]);` is really not a very good idea, although I'm a little surprised that it doesn't work. Much better is `yyless(0);`, which in this case does exactly the same thing (arranges for the character just scanned to be rescanned in a different start condition), but without doing nearly as much work. In particular, it does not need to modify the input buffer, so it will not fail in the same way that `unput` does.

The problem with `unput` appears to be that flex cannot relocate the unconsumed input in the current buffer because the current buffer is exactly the size needed to hold the input. It's not clear to me why it feels that it needs to relocated the input, though.